# What are the equivalent methods of the following native API functions?

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-3.5, c++-cli

I am looking for the equivalent methods (in .Net) of the following WinAPI:

- CreateFile(); or OpenFile();
- CreateFileMapping();
- MapViewOfFile();

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/357207/102937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 4.0 developers, the interesting classes that work with memory-mapped files live in the new System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles namespace.

See this article: http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3828586/Using-Memory-Mapped-Files-in-NET-40.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can use those functions directly. The .net [wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles%28VS.100%29.aspx)  of the memory mapped file API were only introduced in .net 4.0.