# How to open a file in memory?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have see this term branded around but I don't really understand how you open a file in memory.

I have the files written to disk in a temp location but this needs cleaning when a certain form closes and I can't do it when it's open. It's a must that this folder gets emptied. I was wondering if I opened files in memory instead whether it would make a difference?

Comment: It thoroughly depends on what you're doing.

Comment: i have thumbnails displayed on the right - the user double clicks one and it opens the pdf file.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
MemoryStream inMemoryCopy = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
  fs.CopyTo(inMemoryCopy);
}
// Now you can delete the file at 'path' and still have an in memory copy
```

Comment: dam it, we are using .net 3.5 and as such i cant use fs.copyto

Comment: you can easily replicate that CopyTo extension method yourself. Search here.

Comment: you mean search stack over flow for copy to extension method?

Comment: yes there were some very good suggestions mimicking the original CopyTo method in .net 4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c the filestream becomes input, the inmemory stream becomes output right? how do i then display that file? sorry to be a pain i am just massively confused!

Comment: true. Open(..) sort of methods usually accept either file path or stream as input. Use the methods accepting stream as the parameter then you're good to go.

Comment: on what type of object are we talking here - an adobe object?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to work with Memory Mapped files added recently to .NET 4.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx

[Memory Mapped Files .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357170/memory-mapped-files-net)

Comment: Good thinking but memory mapped files still retain their mapping to the original file and write back any in-memory changes to the file after un-mapping, so not that useful in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DeleteOnClose` parameter of `FileStream` constructor:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("<Path Here>", FileMode.Create,
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

and the file will be deleted when closed.

Answer (score 4):

I think it means to read the content of that file into memory as a whole and then close the connection to the file. Assuming it's a file that's not too big you could just read it into a byte[]:

```
byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

If it's a text file read it into a string using

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Once you've done that use a StreamReader to read it later as you would a file on disk.